# What does this sentence mean by "my cold came out of remission"?

Tags: meaning, collocation

What does the part "my cold came out of remission" mean in the following sentence?

> It seems that my cold came out of remission…
>   I'll work from home today and hopefully kick it before Monday.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remission is, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remission_%28medicine%29#Remission), a medical term for

> the state of absence of disease activity in patients known to have incurable chronic illness.

So the sentence would mean something like:

> I thought my cold was gone, but it reappeared [it came out of the state of remission, the absence of activity].

Usually the term *remission* is used for more serious diseases, with a chronic aspect, like cancer.

Comment: +1. It's curious; I don't precisely know why but its strikes me as somewhat perverse to use 'remission' when referring to colds. I'll leave it to others to argue whether is is technically correct, but I think that it's best reserved for more serious conditions.

Comment: This use of "remission" is a form of hyperbole.

Answer (score 3):

It's another way of saying

> I have a cold.

If an illness goes into [*"remission"*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remission), the illness is abating, i.e. lessening (def. 3). Thus, something coming out of *"remission"* is growing stronger.

From a medical standpoint, I don't believe (although I am not a physician) this is medically correct–unlike cancer, a cold is not something that once contracted, persists (whether with or without noticeable symptoms) in the host, assuming no medical intervention takes place, but it's still a nice way of saying it.